# How to append one column data frames to empty columns in worksheet of xlsx file in R?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I would like to automatically run a script daily in which I append one column data frames to existing tables in certain worksheets of xlsx files. I have an xlsx file which contains epidemiological data about the spread and severity of COVID-19 in The Netherlands. Because the website that I scrape daily is only publicing current status rapports, I'm making data frames with trends myself. Everyday I want to append an one column data frame to a worksheet containing daily cumulative updates about the amount of people infected by COVID-19. This data frame needs to be appended at the end of the table in the first empty column. I tried this code:

addDataFrame(Meldingen, sheet = 'Meldingen', col.names = F, row.names = F
             , startRow = 1, startColumn = 10)

But this code overwrites the data in the xlsx file instead of appending it to the the table in the worksheet. Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes surrounding in your formula "Meldingen" won't help. You could try something like this (example with the iris data set). To understand the process, prepare an .xlsx file named "COVID19", with a sheet "Meldingen" containing 10 lines of random data (start in A1) and the number of columns you want (no headers). The 10 first lines of the last column of the iris dataset will be added to the file (in the first empty column).

```
# Open the source .xlsx file (the receiver of the data)
source=read.xlsx("COVID19.xlsx","Meldingen",header = FALSE)

# Get the last computed column of the df which has to be added to the .xlsx file
data=as.data.frame(iris[1:10,ncol(iris)])

# Create the workbook and the sheet (even if they already exist)
wb = createWorkbook()
sheet = createSheet(wb, "Meldingen")

# Get information about the existing sheet (the first empty column)
i=dim(source)[2]+1

# Add the data from the source .xlsx file
addDataFrame(source, sheet=sheet, row.names=FALSE, col.names =FALSE,  startRow = 1)
# Add the data from the R df
addDataFrame(data, sheet=sheet, row.names=FALSE, col.names =FALSE,  startRow = 1, startColumn = i)

# Overwrite the existing file
saveWorkbook(wb, "COVID19.xlsx")
```

Replace `data=as.data.frame(iris[1:10,ncol(iris)])` with `data=as.data.frame(Meldingen[,ncol(iris)])` assuming "Meldingen" is the name of your dataframe in R.